# xcode 9.4.1 console filter crashes when breakpoint hit

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I am trying to search some strings when breakpoint hit. When I try to write something on console filter, xcode crashes all the time. By the way, I do not prefer to upgrade my Xcode version.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you can always reproduce, file a bug report to Apple. if they acknowledge the bug, you'll eventually have to update.

Comment: And it may sound a bit dumb, but in my experience, Xcode's problems often go away after removing derived data + restarting Xcode. Sometimes even restarting the computer helps.

Comment: @regina_fallangi I have already tried to clean derived data and all the other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No crash here when doing this on Xcode 10